# When using model inheritance, is there a way to provide a single alternative/translation for the shared parts?

Tags: lektor

I'm using template inheritance, and the shared/inherited part of the template has variables to be filled in. To handle this in the model, I have a model that corresponds to the shared template and its variables. This shared model is inherited by all of the page models.

I'm also using alternatives for multiple languages in the content.

However, since content doesn't seem to support any sort of inheritance, I find I'm having to provide identical translations for the inherited model elements in each page. That is, I don't see an analogue to model inheritance in the content definition.

Is there are canonical way to avoid this duplication of translation? Is there some form of "content inheritance"? Databags seem to provide a solution, but if feels a bit clunky, and I'm worried about having to explain to the site's ultimate maintainer that there are two ways to do translations.